# Running Xamarin.Forms App on Different Devices [Error: install_failed_missing_shared_library]

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a Xamarin.Forms application that uses native barcode scanning capabilities of the mobile device. I have integrated two different device SDKS from different manufacturers (Casio & Denso).

The main launcer is `SplashActivity`, which shows the splash screen, detects device info and launces one of the following:

- `CasioActivity`
- `DensoActivity`

These activities are responsible for subscribing to scan events raised by corresponding device.

Denso integration is done with a DLL file supplied by the manufacturer, while Casio integration is done through a Xamarin Bindings project, [following this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/).

Deployment to Casio works fine but when I deploy the application on the Denso unit, I get the following error message in Visual Studio:

```
install_failed_missing_shared_library device.sdk is required
```

I believe that the Casio SDK (*.aar file) is forcing that the app runs only on Casio devices. I tried adding the following to the application manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="device.sdk" android:required="false" />
```

and also tried adding the `UsesLibrary` attribute to all activities to make `device.sdk` optional but none worked. It appears that the bindings project is injecting the following to the manifest file on deployment:

```
<uses-library android:name="device.sdk" android:required="true" />
```

Is there any way to prevent the injection of the above line into the manifest file?

I would like to make the application compatible with both of these units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the aar file.

1. Use 7zip to extract the aar file to a folder
2. Find the application manifest in the extracted folder
3. Set `android:required` attribute to false.
4. Zip the folder again
5. Change the file extension from `.zip` to `.aar`
6. Put the new file under `Jars` folder as [shown here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/)